# Relation between the orientation preserving flow and the eigenvalues of the stable and unstable manifolds?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, manifolds, dynamical-systems

Consider the 3D Dynamical system $\dot{X} = F_{\mu}(X)$, Say that the stable and unstable manifolds of the fixed point at $\mu = 0$ intersect each other(Homoclinic tangency to a periodic orbit $C$ of period $\tau_{c}$).

I am referring this article - Homoclinic Orbits and Mixed-Mode Oscillations
in Far-from-Equilibrium Systems by Gaspard and Wang.

Let $\lambda_{s},\lambda_{u}$ denote the eigenvalues of the stable and unstable manifolds, where we have the condition that $|\lambda_{s}|<1<|\lambda_{u}|<\frac{1}{|\lambda_{s}|}$.

Then I was trying to understand how to prove the following statement below -

"Since the flow preserves orientation in the phase space $\Bbb{R}^3$, either $\lambda_{s},\lambda_{u} <0$ OR $\lambda_{s},\lambda_{u}>0$" ?

Any reference or idea of the proof?

Comment: How do stable and unstable manifolds intersect each other **to periodic orbit**? What does that mean?

Comment: Please see the edit.

Comment: Perhaps the authors introduced their own peculiar notation $\lambda_s$ and $\lambda_u$ (without knowing the context I cannot say). But as the possibility $\lambda_u<0$ is admitted, $\lambda_u$ cannot denote the eigenvalue corresponding to the unstable manifold.

Comment: Thanks, for the context I have given the article name!

Comment: Perhaps $\lambda_u$ and $\lambda_s$ denote the eigenvalues of the linearization of the Poincaré map at the periodic orbit $C$? That would make sense.

Comment: I think that I see: the linearization of the Poincaré map has positive determinant, and, since the determinant equals the product of the eigenvalues, they must be both positive or both negative.

Comment: Seems nice, but not getting the linearization of the Poincare map?, also there is a chat room on [Dynamical Systems and Chaos theory](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55403/dynamical-systems-and-chaos-theory) if we can discuss?@user539887